# What creature of CR 5 or lower has the highest Constitution saving throw bonus?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, monster-design, zombies

What creature of CR 5 or lower has the highest Constitution saving throw bonus?

I am currently DMing a campaign and have slowly been introducing higher and higher Con save creatures as zombies, as a local necromancer tries finding the best.

[Zombies](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/zombie)' Undead Fortitude trait says:

> If damage reduces the zombie to 0 hit points, it must make a Constitution saving throw with a DC of 5 + the damage taken, unless the damage is radiant or from a critical hit. On a success, the zombie drops to 1 hit point instead.

Players have been having lots of fun with Zombie bear jokes at the zombie that stood back up six times.
I tried looking myself but currently don't have a lot of time to search before the session this weekend due to my work schedule changing.

#### Requirements

- CR 5 or lower
- Can't be an elemental or something that is already undead
- Would prefer to avoid a fey due to already having done 2 zombie
  redcaps and a zombie yeth hound
- Any published 5e books are fair game. (If you want to do an honorable
  mention from a previous edition, just state the edition so I can look
  at it and transfer it over.)

Answer (score 25):

## Barbed Devils and Otyughs (with a +7 mod to Con saves)

It's possible to use D&D Beyond to get a filtered monster list that answers this question. You can do this by selecting all monster types except fey, elemental, and undead, then filtering to CR 0-5 creatures, and filtering to monsters proficient in Con saves using the advanced filter.

[Here's the final list, sorted from highest to lowest CR (since higher-CR creatures are likely to have higher modifiers).](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=1&filter-type=2&filter-type=3&filter-type=4&filter-type=6&filter-type=9&filter-type=10&filter-type=11&filter-type=13&filter-type=14&filter-type=15&filter-search=&filter-cr-min=1&filter-cr-max=9&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-save-proficiency=3&filter-is-legendary=&filter-has-lair=&sort=-cr) The top 4 in the list:

- [Barbed Devil](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/barbed-devil) (a total modifier of +7 to Con saves)
- [Barlgura](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/barlgura) (+6 to Con saves) - MM, p. 56
- [Brontosaurus](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/brontosaurus) (+6) - VGtM, p. 139
- [Cambion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/cambion) (+6) - MM, p. 36

There are a few others with a +6 or +5 mod, but I decided to skip ahead to another tied for the highest:

- [Otyugh](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/otyugh) (+7)

I'm not seeing any others with a +7 modifier or higher for Con saves.

Comment: Zombie Brontosaurus .... that's a great visual

Comment: Ikr!! Haha thanks for the help and ill remember dnd beyond in future!!

Answer (score 3):

Just going over CR5 encounters (since they should have the most CON) here are a few that I found -

1. [Banderhobb](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/banderhobb) (from Volo's, p. 122) with 20 CON (+5)
2. [Bulette](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Bulette#content) with 21 CON (+5)
3. [Giant Shark](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Giant%20Shark#content) with 21 CON (+5)
4. [Tanarukk](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/tanarukk) (from Volo's, p. 186) (fiend) with 20 CON (+5)
5. [Troll](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Troll#content) with 20 CON (+5)
6. [Catoblepas](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/catoblepas) (from Volo's, p. 129) with 21 CON (+5)

Only found one fiend with a high CON (+5) under CR5 which adds to your flavor
(and I dont think you can use a shark for your setting given your party has been fighting bears)

If I happen to have missed any high con non-elementals please feel free to edit them in

Comment: [Relevant meta.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7210/33569) The site you've linked to for the non-SRD monsters hosts/shares non-SRD content, which goes against RPG.SE's policy against piracy. I'd suggest changing the links to point to D&D Beyond instead, and probably adding page numbers so it's accessible to those who don't own it digitally.

Comment: @V2Blast Thank you for mentioning that, and thanks for the edit

Comment: Thanks for help!! And can still use zombie shark because undead don't have to breath so it doesn't need water XD.  Would prob only have 10 movement but still funny :3